# How to download Landsat8 data from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Below is my code and it runs perfectly but when I run the unsubmitted task in gee,it gives this error:

> Error: Image.setDefaultProjection, argument 'image': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection.
> (Error code: 3)

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterBounds(geometry)
      .filterDate('2019-11-17', '2020-03-31')


// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);
  
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
              .updateMask(qaMask)
              .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};


Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'True Color (432)');

Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: dataset,
  description: 'Landsat8_for_NDBI',
  scale: 10, 
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
  region: geometry 
});
```

Can you help me to bypass this?

Comment: In your script, `dataset` is not an image but an image collection. You cannot pass an ImageCollection to `image` parameter of `toDrive` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the awesome [`geetools`](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor) from [Rodrigo E. Principe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe) for exporting an ImageCollection to Drive:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(dataset,'Some_folder',{
  scale: 10, 
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
  region: geometry 
});
```

Comment: I had an error :In users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch
Line 133: collection.size is not a function

Comment: @AugustusInyang check the parenthesis, imageCollection and folder are out of curly brackets. That error is because the function didn't load an imageCollection. It works for me: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d8fd26868308b75839634e32b235399

Comment: Sorry I actually corrected it, but the issue is the page keeps freezing and becomes unresponsive

Comment: @AugustusInyang maybe the study area is too big or the date range takes too many scenes. Try it with a small date range first for debugging purposes

Comment: I guess you are right, because after waiting for a couple of time, lots of task started loading, and the issue now is that, after downloading one of the task then imported to Arcmap, the landsat image is a no data

Comment: @AugustusInyang you applied scale factors for getting reflectance values. I suggest you add an `image * 10000` or `image * 1000`. Maybe the issue is related to datatype (float) since I have used this function many times without issues. I always apply a scale factor and download the scenes as Int8 or Int16, images are lighter

Comment: is there a way I can download just 2 to 3 bands from the landsat 8

Comment: Yes, using `.select(['SR_B2','SR_B3',SR_B4'])` for example. Since you're exporting a collection, you need to map over it for getting only the bands you want